# How can you partition every value of a dictionary and change that value to the first output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Let's say I have the dict:

```
dict = {
    '1': 'robert; james; pasta',
    '2': 'peas; cupcake; happy times; peas'}
```

the dict would have multiple pairs so you need to go through them all

I need to get it to go through them all and transform it to:

```
dict = {
    '1': 'robert',
    '2': 'peas'}
```

how could I do this? I know you need to use partition.

I tried:

```
 for i in questionanswerclean.values():
        ram = i.partition(';')
        print(i)
        questionanswerclean[i] = ram
```

Comment: what you show us is not a dictionary and not valid python syntax. please explain yourself better and show us the desored output.

Comment: ok I fixed the issue you two stated

Comment: where did this harry come from?

Comment: sorry! I meant to type peas

Comment: now it's clear, I answered :)

Comment: `{'1': 'robert','2': 'peas'}` why `robert` and `peas`

Comment: i mean; I was just thinking of words. the content of the dictionary is not really that vital anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ovewrites dic with the same dictionary where each value is the first one of the string when you split at `;`.

**Note:** Don't name your dictionary `dict` because that's a language built-in name.

```
dic = {
    '1': 'robert; james; pasta',
    '2': 'peas; cupcake; happy times; peas'
}

dic = {key: val.split(';')[0] for key, val in dic.items()}
print(dic)
```

Output:

```
{'1': 'robert', '2': 'peas'}
```

Answer (score 0):

indeed your approach was correct, you just needed to use `[]` to access the first item (same result can be achieved with slicing or `spilt`):

```
old_dict = {
    '1': 'robert; james; pasta',
    '2': 'peas; cupcake; happy times; peas'
}
new_dict = {}
for key in old_dict:
    old_dict[key] = old_dict[key].partition(';')[0]
```

resulting in:
`{'1': 'robert', '2': 'peas'}`

Comment: do you need to make a new dict or can you replace stuff in the old one?

Comment: @JustOscarJ you can replace, just change `new_dict[key] = ...` to `old_dict[key] = ...`

Comment: @JustOscarJ I updated the code to make it easier for you